# Converting Between Timezones in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

I am trying to understand the timestamps and timezones in Postgre. I think I got it, until I red [this](http://phili.pe/posts/timestamps-and-time-zones-in-postgresql/) article. 
 Focus on the "Converting Between Timezones" part. It has two examples.

(Consider the default timezone configuration to be UTC.)

Example 1

```
db=# SELECT timezone('US/Pacific', '2016-01-01 00:00'); outputs 2015-12-31 16:00:00
```

According to the article and what I understand, because the `'2016-01-01 00:00'` part of the `timezone` function is just a string, it is silently converted to the default UTC. So from `'2016-01-01 00:00' UTC` it is then converted to `US/Pacific` as asked by the `timezone` function, that is `2015-12-31 16:00:00`.

Example 2

```
db=# SELECT timezone('US/Pacific', '2016-01-01 00:00'::timestamp); outputs 2016-01-01 08:00:00+00
```

Excuse me, I dont see why and the explanation there does not help. Ok, the `'2016-01-01 00:00'::timestamp` part of the `timezone` function is no longer a string, but an actual timestamp. In what timezone? If it is UTC, the output would have to be the same as the Example 1. So it is automatically converted to `US/Pacific`? Then the output is in UTC? But why? I asked for a `US/Pacific` in my `timezone`  not a UTC.

Please explain how the `timezone` behaves when gets a timestamp and gets asked to transform it. Thank you.

Comment: The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) are quite informative if you haven't seen them yet.
Excerpt: `For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC. An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be in the time zone indicated by the system's TimeZone parameter, and is converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.`

Comment: @bma No offence, but you are not helping me. I have seen the docs. The default timezone for both examples is UTC. Example 2 has time zone data. So internally it is stored as UTC. The default timezone also happens to be UTC in this case . So it should be the same as example 1.  It is not? Why? Unless string to UTC and timestamp to UTC give different results. Thanks

Comment: You're right, that wasn't very helpful on re-reading your question (my apologies for that). There is a thorough answer at [timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170) but it didn't seem to address the implicit string -> timestamp -> timestamptz conversion you demonstrated. If you cast the string explicitly and define the timestamp, you get same results in #2 as in #1. `SELECT timezone('US/Pacific', '2016-01-01 00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'UTC');`

Comment: @bma I finally got it. I think. Check my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Let me explain the two examples:

In both we assume a timezone UTC (i.e. `SET timezone TO UTC`).

```
db=# SELECT timezone('US/Pacific', '2016-01-01 00:00');
      timezone
---------------------
 2015-12-31 16:00:00
(1 row)
```

This is equivalent to `SELECT timezone('US/Pacific', '2016-01-01 00:00'::timestamptz)`, i.e. Postgres implicitly converted the string to a `timestamptz`.

We know that the `timezone` function converts back and forth between `timestamp` and `timestamptz`:

[image]

Since we are giving it a `timestamptz` as input, it'll output a `timestamp`. In other words, it is converting the absolute point in time `2016-01-01 00:00Z` to a wall time in `US/Pacific`, i.e. what the clock in Los Angeles showed at that absolute point in time.

In example 2 we are doing the opposite, namely taking a `timestamp` and converting it to a `timestamptz`. In other words, we are asking: what was the absolute point in time when the clock in Los Angeles showed `2016-01-01 00:00`?

You mention:

> Ok, the `'2016-01-01 00:00'::timestamp` part of the timezone function is no longer a string, but an actual timestamp. In what timezone?

`'2016-01-01 00:00'::timestamp` is a `timestamp`, i.e. a wall time. It doesn't have a notion of timezone.

I think you might not have fully understood the difference between `timestamp` and `timestamptz`, which is key here. Just think of them as *wall time*, i.e. the time that showed somewhere in the world on a clock hanging on the wall, and *absolute time*, i.e. the absolute time in our universe.

The examples you make in your own answer are not quite accurate.

```
SELECT ts FROM  (VALUES
(timestamptz '2012-03-05 17:00:00+0') -- outputs 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00 --1
,(timestamptz '2012-03-05 18:00:00+1') -- outputs 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00 --2
,(timestamp   '2012-03-05 18:00:00+1') -- outputs 2012-03-05 18:00:00+00 --3
,(timestamp   '2012-03-05 11:00:00'  AT TIME ZONE '+6') -- outputs 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00 --4
,(timestamp   '2012-03-05 17:00:00'  AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') -- outputs 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00 --5
,(timestamp   '2012-03-05 17:00:00'::timestamp) -- outputs 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00 --6
,(timestamp   '2012-03-05 17:00:00'::timestamptz) -- outputs 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00 --7
    ) t(ts);
```

The problem with your example is that you're constructing one data set with a single column. Since a column can only have one type, each row (or single value in this case) is being converted to the same type, namely `timestamptz`, even though some values were calculated as `timestamp` (e.g. value 3). Thus, you have an additional implicit conversion here.

Let's split the example into separate queries and see what is going on:

**Example 1**

```
db=# SELECT timestamptz '2012-03-05 17:00:00+0';
      timestamptz
------------------------
 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00
```

As you might already know, `timestamptz '2012-03-05 17:00:00+0'` and `'2012-03-05 17:00:00+0'::timestamptz` are equivalent (I prefer the latter). Thus, just to use the same syntax as in the article, I'll rewrite:

```
db=# SELECT '2012-03-05 17:00:00+0'::timestamptz;
      timestamptz
------------------------
 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00
```

Now, what's going on here? Well, less than in your original explanation. The string is simply parsed as a `timestamptz`. When the result gets printed, it uses the currently set `timezone` config to convert it back to a human readable representation of the underlying data structure, i.e. `2012-03-05 17:00:00+00`.

Let's change the `timezone` config and see what happens:

```
db=# SET timezone TO 'Europe/Berlin';
SET
db=# SELECT '2012-03-05 17:00:00+0'::timestamptz;
      timestamptz
------------------------
 2012-03-05 18:00:00+01
```

The only thing that changed is *how* the `timestamptz` gets printed on screen, namely using the **Europe/Berlin** timezone.

**Example 2**

```
db=# SELECT timestamptz '2012-03-05 18:00:00+1';
      timestamptz
------------------------
 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

Again, just parsing the date.

**Example 3**

```
db=# SELECT timestamp '2012-03-05 18:00:00+1';
      timestamp
---------------------
 2012-03-05 18:00:00
(1 row)
```

This is the same as `'2012-03-05 18:00:00+1'::timestamp`. What happens here is that the timezone offset is simply ignored because you're asking for a `timestamp`.

**Example 4**

```
db=# SELECT timestamp '2012-03-05 11:00:00' AT TIME ZONE '+6';
        timezone
------------------------
 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

Let's rewrite to be simpler:

```
db=# SELECT timezone('+6', '2012-03-05 11:00:00'::timestamp);
        timezone
------------------------
 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

This is asking: what was the absolute time when the clock on the wall in the timezone with an offset of +6 hours was showing `2012-03-05 11:00:00`?

**Example 5**

```
db=# SELECT timestamp '2012-03-05 17:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
        timezone
------------------------
 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

Let's rewrite:

```
db=# SELECT timezone('UTC', '2012-03-05 17:00:00'::timestamp);
        timezone
------------------------
 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

This is asking: what was the absolute time when the clock on the wall in the timezone UTC was showing `2012-03-05 17:00:00`?

**Example 6**

```
db=# SELECT timestamp '2012-03-05 17:00:00'::timestamp;
      timestamp
---------------------
 2012-03-05 17:00:00
(1 row)
```

Here you're casting twice to `timestamp`, which makes no difference. Let's simplify:

```
db=# SELECT '2012-03-05 17:00:00'::timestamp;
      timestamp
---------------------
 2012-03-05 17:00:00
(1 row)
```

That's clear I think.

**Example 7**

```
db=# SELECT timestamp '2012-03-05 17:00:00'::timestamptz;
      timestamptz
------------------------
 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

Let's rewrite:

```
db=# SELECT ('2012-03-05 17:00:00'::timestamp)::timestamptz;
      timestamptz
------------------------
 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

You're first parsing the string as a `timestamp` and then converting it to a `timestamptz` using the currently set `timezone`. If we change the `timezone`, we get something else because Postgres assumes that timezone when converting a `timestamp` (or a string lacking timezone information) to `timestamptz`:

```
db=# SET timezone TO 'Europe/Berlin';
SET
db=# SELECT ('2012-03-05 17:00:00'::timestamp)::timestamptz;
      timestamptz
------------------------
 2012-03-05 17:00:00+01
(1 row)
```

This absolute time, expressed in UTC, is `2012-03-05 16:00:00+00`, thus different from the original example.

---

I hope this clarifies things. Again, understanding the difference between `timestamp` and `timestamptz` is key. Think of wall time versus absolute time.

Comment: `timestamptz` parses any offset so the date can be readable. `timestamp` ignores it , because there is no such concept.  Any actual conversion (not parsing) is done when a specific timezone is specified. `timezone` converts from `timezone`(clock) to `timezonetz`(global) and vice versa. Any final additional conversion is made if a different timezone is defined with `SET` or in the `postgresql.conf`. This is the "golden rules". I think I got it now. Thank you so much for the time and the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I understand. Please bare with me.
My default timezone, defined in the `postgresql.conf` is UTC. Check this code

```
SELECT ts FROM  (VALUES
(timestamptz '2012-03-05 17:00:00+0') -- outputs 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00 --1
,(timestamptz '2012-03-05 18:00:00+1') -- outputs 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00 --2
,(timestamp   '2012-03-05 18:00:00+1') -- outputs 2012-03-05 18:00:00+00 --3
,(timestamp   '2012-03-05 11:00:00'  AT TIME ZONE '+6') -- outputs 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00 --4
,(timestamp   '2012-03-05 17:00:00'  AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') -- outputs 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00 --5
,(timestamp   '2012-03-05 17:00:00'::timestamp) -- outputs 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00 --6
,(timestamp   '2012-03-05 17:00:00'::timestamptz) -- outputs 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00 --7
    ) t(ts);
```

Now, pretend this is Postgre talking : 
There is special timezone defined for the output. So I will output everything in the default UTC. Lets go.

1 `(timestamptz '2012-03-05 17:00:00+0')`
This is time-aware data, the offset is 0, so its UTC. The default is also UTC. I will save it as is (no need to convert) and output `2012-03-05 17:00:00+00` because UTC input to UTC save to UTC output.

2 `(timestamptz '2012-03-05 18:00:00+1')`
Also time-aware data, the offset is +1, so its not UTC. Offset by minus 1 to convert it to UTC, so I can save it as UTC, that is the default. Output `2012-03-05 17:00:00+00` because not-UTC input to UTC save to UTC output.

3 `(timestamp   '2012-03-05 18:00:00+1')`
Time-unaware data. Ignore the offset, assume this is the default UTC and save it as is. Output `2012-03-05 18:00:00+00` because, I-dont-know-I-dont-care-I-will-pretend-this-is-my-default-UTC-input to UTC save to UTC output.

4 `(timestamp   '2012-03-05 11:00:00'  AT TIME ZONE '+6')`
Again time-unaware data. Ignore the offset, if any. Then convert it to the given `AT TIME ZONE '+6'` offset so I can treat it as a complete time-unaware data. So my final data is `2012-03-05 17:00:00+00`. But this is still not time-aware data. So, I will assume this is my default UTC and save it as is. Output `2012-03-05 17:00:00+00` because, I-dont-know-I-dont-care-I-will-pretend-this-is-my-default-UTC-input to UTC save to UTC output.

5 `(timestamp   '2012-03-05 17:00:00'  AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')`
Like the previous data, time-unaware data. I will ignore the offset, if any. Then I will convert it to the given `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`, so no actual conversion, because there is no actual offset (UTC offset is 0). So my final data is `2012-03-05 17:00:00`. But this is still not time-aware data. So, I will assume this is my default UTC and save it as is. Output `2012-03-05 17:00:00` because, I-dont-know-I-dont-care-I-will-pretend-this-is-my-default-UTC-input to UTC save to UTC output

6 `(timestamp   '2012-03-05 17:00:00'::timestamp)`
This is time-unaware data , converted to time-unaware data again. So, like 4, I will ignore any offset , if any. There is no `AT TIME ZONE` either, so no conversions. My final time-unaware data is `'2012-03-05 17:00:00'`. I will assume this is my default UTC and save it as is. Output `2012-03-05 17:00:00+00` because, I-dont-know-I-dont-care-I-will-pretend-this-is-my-default-UTC-input to UTC save to UTC output

7 `(timestamp   '2012-03-05 17:00:00'::timestamptz)`
This is time-unaware data , converted to time-aware data. But there is no offset, conversion, nothing. So, this is UTC. So, I will save it as is. Output `2012-03-05 17:00:00+00` because UTC input to UTC save to UTC output.

(Hope the above will help anyone, in general)

**NOW! Regarding the article**
**Example 1**
`SELECT timezone('US/Pacific', '2016-01-01 00:00');` 
Time-unaware data, but I can convert it to time-aware. According to the [article](http://phili.pe/posts/timestamps-and-time-zones-in-postgresql/), since there is no time zone information, it can be parsed in the default UTC timezone. 
So, time-aware, UTC data, save it as is, but convert it to `US/Pacific` before output it. This is why [article](http://phili.pe/posts/timestamps-and-time-zones-in-postgresql/) says "We get the wall time in California for 2016-01-01 00:00 UTC. " Output is `2015-12-31 16:00:00`, that is the wall time in California, for the `'2016-01-01 00:00'` UTC input.

[Article](http://phili.pe/posts/timestamps-and-time-zones-in-postgresql/) also says "Note that we passed the timestamp as a string, which was implicitly cast to a timestamptz". 
This could be written as `SELECT timezone('US/Pacific', '2016-01-01 00:00'::timestamptz);` and still output `2015-12-31 16:00:00`. Time-aware data, no offset, so its offset 0, so its UTC. UTC is also the default, so just save it as is. Convert it to `US/Pacific` before outputting it. This is why it outputs `2015-12-31 16:00:00` again.

Since "`timezone(zone, timestamp)` is equivalent to the SQL-conforming construct `timestamp AT TIME ZONE zone`", according to the [article](http://phili.pe/posts/timestamps-and-time-zones-in-postgresql/), then

```
SELECT timezone('US/Pacific', '2016-01-01 00:00');
SELECT timezone('US/Pacific', '2016-01-01 00:00'::timestamptz);
timestamptz '2016-01-01 00:00' at time zone 'US/Pacific'
timestamptz '2016-01-01 00:00+00' at time zone 'US/Pacific'
```

are **all the same**
Time-aware data (or make it be time-aware), no offset, save it as UTC, output it converted, as  `US/Pacific`.

**Example 2**
`SELECT timezone('US/Pacific', '2016-01-01 00:00'::timestamp);`
Time-unaware data. Can I convert it to the UTC default, like in Example 1? No, because is converted to time-unaware (`::timestamp` part). There is nothing I can do. It is time-aware data.

I will ignore the offset, if any. Unlike 4 above, there is no offset defined, no `AT TIME ZONE '+ or -X'`. So, to get the UTC I will convert the `'2016-01-01 00:00'` back to UTC, according to the `US/Pacific`. Add 8 hours to go from Pacific to UTC. My UTC now is `2016-01-01 08:00:00+00`. Save it as is. Output `2016-01-01 08:00:00+00` because, I-dont-know-I-dont-care-I-will-pretend-this-is-my-default-UTC-input to UTC save to UTC output

Again, according to the [article](http://phili.pe/posts/timestamps-and-time-zones-in-postgresql/) "`timezone(zone, timestamp)` is equivalent to the SQL-conforming construct `timestamp AT TIME ZONE zone`", so

```
SELECT timezone('US/Pacific', '2016-01-01 00:00'::timestamp);
timestamp '2016-01-01 00:00' at time zone 'US/Pacific'
timestamp '2016-01-01 00:00+00' at time zone 'US/Pacific'
```

are **all the same**

Time-unaware data, ignore offset, convert back to UTC, this is UTC, save as UTC output as UTC.

Thanks

Comment: Your question reminded of a book that was released recently about this topic, which you may or may not find interesting: http://korban.net/postgres/book/. I'm not affiliated in any way, but reviewing the site, it looks like it pretty conclusively covers this topic.