# Different TimeZone outputs wrong values

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I am wondering why I am getting different times from this post [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48069425/converting-between-timezones-in-postgre)

```
set timezone to 'UTC';

SELECT timestamptz '2012-03-05 17:00:00+0';  
Expected :2012-03-05 17:00:00+00
Got : 2012-03-05 22:30:00

SET timezone TO 'Europe/Berlin';

SELECT '2012-03-05 17:00:00+0'::timestamptz;  
Expected :  2012-03-05 18:00:00+01
Got: 2012-03-05 22:30:00



SELECT timestamptz '2012-03-05 18:00:00+1';
Expected : 2012-03-05 17:00:00+00
Got : 2012-03-05 22:30:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I am using `DBeaver` as a DB IDE and there we need to do some adjustments in `dbeaver.ini` refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323552/how-to-change-dbeaver-timezone-how-to-stop-dbeaver-from-converting-date-and-ti) for more insight

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is how you are setting your timezone.

Can you try changing `SET timezone TO` to `SET TIME ZONE` and see if it works?

You can see the documentation below for more help:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES

Comment: [The docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-set.html) say: "`SET TIME ZONE value` is an alias for `SET timezone TO value`."

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations are correct. The problem must be that you are running the statements in different database sessions.

The scope of `SET` is limited to the current session.