# In Postgres, how to generate a UTC timestamp with timezone column from a text column with YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ dates

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

My table has a "Timestamp" column (text type) with YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ formatted dates.  I want to generate a timestamptz formatted column with a continuous UTC timestamp but have been unable to do it.  I have tried many methods suggested in forums and documentation but I have not been able to get anything to work.

Here is a data example from the table:

```
select "Timestamp",("Timestamp"::timestamp with time zone) from public.time_177168 limit 1
```

This returns:

"2022-12-10T04:10:02-06:00" (Text)   and "2022-12-10 10:10:02+00" (timestamp with time zone)

Here are a few examples of my attempts to generate the new column but they all return:

ERROR:  generation expression is not immutable SQL state: 42P17

Attempt 1:

```
alter table public.time_177168 ADD COLUMN "TimestampUTC" timestamp with time zone GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("Timestamp"::timestamp with time zone) STORE
```

Attempt 2:

```
alter table public.time_177168 ADD COLUMN "TimestampUTC" timestamp with time zone GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("Timestamp"::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'ETC/UTC') STORED
```

The overall goal is to be able to quickly order queries by UTC time. I am not able to change the data type for the existing "Timestamp" column because of legacy applications that use this database.

Any ideas or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Additional Information:
Using the solution below I was able to get the query performance to an acceptable level.

**Original Query:**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT "Timestamp","Column1","Column2","Column3"  FROM time_177168 WHERE "Timestamp">'2022-11-06T00:59:00-06:00' ORDER BY ("Timestamp"::timestamp with time zone) limit 5000
```

**Query Plan:**

```
Limit  (cost=125360.32..125943.69 rows=5000 width=81) (actual time=5826.521..5828.301 rows=5000 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=125360.32..198037.52 rows=622904 width=81) (actual time=5826.520..5827.743 rows=5000 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 0
        ->  Sort  (cost=124360.29..125138.92 rows=311452 width=81) (actual time=5826.186..5826.712 rows=5000 loops=1)
              Sort Key: ((Timestamp)::timestamp with time zone)
              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 1089kB
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on time_177168  (cost=0.00..103667.87 rows=311452 width=81) (actual time=0.136..5302.325 rows=747701 loops=1)
                    Filter: (Timestamp > '2022-11-06T00:59:00-06:00'::text)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 438784
Planning Time: 0.145 ms
Execution Time: 5829.070 ms
```

**New Query (Based on Accepted Solution)**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT "Timestamp","Column1","Column2","Column3"  FROM time_177168 WHERE "Timestamp">'2022-11-06T00:59:00-06:00' ORDER BY "TimestampUTC" limit 5000
```

**Query Plan:**

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..2793.20 rows=5000 width=81) (actual time=728.625..748.371 rows=5000 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using timestamputc_time_177168 on time_177168 (cost=0.43..417511.91 rows=747486 width=81) (actual time=728.623..747.778 rows=5000 loops=1)
        Filter: (Timestamp > '2022-11-06T00:59:00-06:00'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 438784
Planning Time: 0.134 ms
Execution Time: 756.844 ms
```

Comment: `"2022-12-10T04:10:02-06:00"` is not exactly in the format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`. What is a *"timestampz formatted column with a continuous UTC timestamp"* exactly? You mean `timestamptz`? What is the exact timestamptz value you expect for the given input? Take the time zone offset into account or not?

Comment: In `psql` what is the result of `show timezone;`? If as I suspect it is `UTC` why create the column? Just do `"Timestamp"::timestamptz` when you need a UTC value in a query.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the clarification.  This TZO stuff is new to me.  I want to take the TZO into account when creating the new column.  The issue is that ordering on the existing text column results in rows being out of order around DLS changes.  If I order the existing column by ("Timestamp"::timestamp with time zone) then the query is about 166x slower.  My thought is that I can order by the new UTC column without this performance hit.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have tried adding "order by ("Timestamp"::timestamp with time zone) to my queries but it is ~166x slower than ordering by "Timestamp" alone.

Comment: **ADD information to question not comments**. What does `show timezone;` return? Add `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output of slow and fast queries to question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for the quick response.  `show timezone;` returns `Etc/UTC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you know the function is truly immutable, you can just declare it as such. So create a function like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION str2timestamp(text) RETURNS timestamp with time zone
   IMMUTABLE SET timezone = 'UTC' LANGUAGE sql
RETURN to_timestamp($1, 'YYYY-MM-DD\THH24:MI:SS);
```

That is safe, because `timezone` is fixed while the function is running.

Such a function can be used to define a generated column using the following steps:

```
ALTER TABLE public.time_177168
   ADD "TimestampUTC" timestamp with time zone
      GENERATED ALWAYS AS (str2timestamp("Timestamp")) STORED;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this informative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48082524/467545) to a somewhat similar question.

This might do the trick for you:

```sql
select "Timestamp",("Timestamp"::timestamp with time zone) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' from public.mx_time_well_177168 limit 1
```

Try adding `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` to it.